# "push" is not a function [on elements returned by getElementsByTagName]

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I have a bit of Javascript where I'm POSTing my form with an XMLHttpRequest, which otherwise works fine, but when I try to add the SELECT values to the array of INPUT values, it seems Javascript has lost its mind (or I have).

This function just builds the "name1=value1&name2=value2" string and passes it along.

The code:

```
function sendTheForm() {
  var postData = '';
  var inputArr = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if (inputArr.hasOwnProperty(length)) alert("ARRAY!!");
  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  var tmpObj = new Object();

  for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    tmpObj.name  = selects[i].name;
    tmpObj.value = selects[i].value;
    inputArr.push(tmpObj);
    }

  for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
    if (inputArr[i].value) {
      if (postData.length) postData += '&';
      postData += inputArr[i].name;
      postData += '=';
      postData += escape(inputArr[i].value);
      }
    }

  makeHttpReq(postData)
  }
```

The error I get in FireFox is: "`inputArr.push is not a function`"  It does say it's an Array.

Now, besides the fact that it's a method (not a function), it seems something is going badly wrong here, it's right under my nose and I can't see it. Help?

Earlier, I tried doing:

```
  len = inputArr.length;
  inputArr[len].name = ...
```

and also got an error that inputArr[31] was undefined.  This is probably obvious, but I'm not seeing it.  Help?

Comment: Hi - I've modified it for you but when you post code it's helpful to select it and press the code block button in the editor (101010 button)

Comment: For your second question: The last item in an array is always `myArray[ myArray.length-1 ]`, since JavaScript arrays are indexed starting at 0.

Comment: An array is an object but an object is not an array.

Comment: Oh, I have to enable Javascript from sstatic.net, and there are the buttons AND the directions on the right. (Sometimes NoScript is a pain.)

Comment: Phrogz - for the second Q, I was trying to ADD an element to the "array."  I think it would have worked fine, had it BEEN an array.  Since NodeLists don't allow adding, no luck.

Comment: @Jeffiekins `var a=[]; a[0].name = "foo" // TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined` If you want to add an element to an array, you need to first create the element and _then_ add it. You can't just set properties on `undefined` and have a new `Object` instance pop into place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a `.length` property does not mean that it is an array. [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://objjob.phrogz.net/dom/method/563) returns a [DOM 2 NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-536297177), not an [Array](http://objjob.phrogz.net/js/object/314).

Comment: Correct, the NodeList is **like** an Array, but not quite ;-)

Comment: I should have paid more attention to Crockford's "remedial Javascript", I guess.   I knew it was something like that, but somehow wasn't seeing it.  Obvious, now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As Phrogz already said, checking for a `length` property is **NOT** a way of checking for an array.

There's only one way to do that, so it works in **ALL** cases.

And that is using `Object.prototype.toString.call(object).slice(8, -1)`.

Which gives you the Class value.

```
  Value               Class      Type
  -------------------------------------
  "foo"               String     string
  new String("foo")   String     object
  1.2                 Number     number
  new Number(1.2)     Number     object
  true                Boolean    boolean
  new Boolean(true)   Boolean    object
  new Date()          Date       object
  new Error()         Error      object
  [1,2,3]             Array      object
  new Array(1, 2, 3)  Array      object
  new Function("")    Function   function
  /abc/g              RegExp     object (function in Nitro/V8)
  new RegExp("meow")  RegExp     object (function in Nitro/V8)
  {}                  Object     object
  new Object()        Object     object
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, under what cases does `a.constructor == Array` fail? Only when the `constructor` property has been specifically assigned, or are there common situations where this shouldn't be trusted?

Comment: This might for example fail when the array comes from another document, like a window you opened or an iframe, because that runs in it's own JS context.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this isn't working is because the `inputArr` variable is actually a node list, not a real *array*.

If you do want it to be an array, you'd loop through it and add all the nodes in it to a real array or you can do this:

```
var node_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(node_list);
```